# On vs. off-plant ripening: which one yields a more nutritious fruit?

Tags: nutrition, fruit

Many fruits may ripen either when attached to the plant, or once it is detached from the plant. Which option yields a more nutritious fruit? In other words, if one picks a fruit when it is still unripe, then wait for it to get ripe, will the fruit has similar nutritional properties as if one wait for the fruit to ripe before picking it?